# eclipse with reportlab

Tags: python, django, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, reportlab

I have an application made in Django which finally uses Reportlab to generate the pdf file by accessing the data from some tables.
There are some imports like:

from rlextra.graphics.guiedit.datacharts import DataAwareDrawing, ODBCDataSource, DataAssociation
from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import VerticalBarChart3D
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import _DrawingEditorMixin

in my reportlab file. I am using Eclipse for generating the Django application. When I included the reportlab py file in the application, its showing errors that these imports can not be resolved.
I included the rlextra and reportlab folders in the application by which the last 2 imports can be resolved by first one couldnt be.

I went inside diving through the rlextra folder to find that,folder guidedit does not contain any folder datacharts by has a pyc file of that name. My eclipse is not understanding what does DataAwareDrawing, ODBCDataSource, DataAssociation mean.

When I run the same reportlab py from outside eclipse separately as a python file it does the work properly. But Eclipse is not understanding what is required and from where to get it.

Comment: I don't know much about Eclipse, but it sounds like it's not finding the location of your site-packages directory.

Answer (score 0):

rlextra is a proprietary addition on top of ReportLab. You only get the .pyc files but not the source .py files when you receive the package. I do remember a packaging issue with datacharts.pyc on version 2.4 that was reported by a client and fixed on the day. If you contact ReportLab they will be more than happy to help you.